# AttributeError: module 'prtscnr' has no attribute 'portscanner'

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, module, attributeerror

> It's part of my login.py module. I imported my prtscnr module at the top of the code.

```
import prtscnr

def menu():
    print("****** Recon ******")
    print("1- PortScanner")
    print("2- Subdomain Finder")
    print("3- Hash Decryption ")
    print("4- Çıkış ")
    msecim = int(input("Seçimini yap: "))
    if msecim == 1 :
        print("Portscanner'a hoşgeldin...")
        prtscnr.portscanner()
```

> It's my prtscnr.py module. I defined portscanner function in it. But when i tried to run it in my login.py it gives me AttributeError: module 'prtscnr' has no attribute 'portscanner'. What should I do?

```
#upgrade. dosya adını ve konumunu kullanıcıdan al. loopu hızlandır.
import socket

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def portscanner():
    # port aralığını başlangıç ve bitiş değerlerine ayır
        target = input("Hedefin IP adresini veya URL'ini girin: ")
        port_range = input("Taranacak olan port aralığını girin (örnek: 1-1000): ")
        start_port, end_port = map(int, port_range.split("-"))

    # açık portları tutmak için bir liste oluştur
        open_ports = []

    # aralıktaki tüm portlar için for döngüsü
        for port in range(start_port, end_port+1):
        # socket oluştur
            client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        # bağlantı girişimi için timeout
            client.settimeout(0.5)
        # hedef IP/Hostname'e bağlantı girişimi
            try:
                response = client.connect_ex((target, port))
            # Bağlantı başarılıysa 0 döndürür ve açık olan portları terminalde yazar
                if response == 0:
                    open_ports.append(port)
                    print("Port {0}: Açık".format(port))
            # socketi kapat
                client.close()
            except:
                pass

    # Açık port numaralarını .txt dosyası içine yazar
        dosya_adi = input("Dosya adını girin: ")
        dosya_konumu = input("Dosya konumunu girin: ")
        with open(dosya_konumu + "\\" + dosya_adi + ".txt", "w") as file:
            file.write("{0} için port {1} den port {2} e kadar olan açık portlar:\n".format(target, start_port, end_port))
            for port in open_ports:
                file.write("{0}\n".format(port))
            print("Open port numbers have been written to {0}".format(dosya_adi))
```

when i try to run `prtscnr.portscanner()` code in to my login.py file i got an error like `AttributeError: module 'prtscnr' has no attribute 'portscanner'` what's wrong? or what should i do?

Comment: When you import that file, `__name__` is not main anymore and thus, prtscnr module is "empty"

Comment: Have you tried moving your entire `portscanner()` function outside of the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block? Why is it inside that anyway?

Comment: I moved <portscanner()>outside and it printed <Portscanner'a hoşgeldin...> but didn't run <portscanner()> and it didn't give an any error line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you check `if __name__ == '__main__'` before defining your function in `prtscnr.py`.

What checking `if __name__ == '__main__'` is used for is to check whether the file being called has been imported by an external file (in which case `__name__` will be equal to the name of the file) or if it is being called directly as the first file of the stack trace (in this case `__name__` is equal to `__main__`).

Here is a demonstration:

`main.py`

```
import file1
print(f'from main file: {__name__}')
```

`file1.py`

```
print(f'from file1: {__name__}')
```

When I run `main.py` the `output` is:

```
from file1: file1
from main file: __main__
```

So that is why your `portscanner` method is not recognized. If you intend to call the file only ever as an import you can completely get rid of the `if __name__ == '__main__'` or replace it with `if __name__ == 'prtscnr'`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: thx bro it worked. i am very beginner at this coding and stuff sorry about that.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I was able to help !